# Como inserir um elemento em uma array[]?

Tags: php, javascript

> ESSE EXEMPLO SÓ ME RETORNA O PRIMEIRO ITEM;

```
   $parcelas = 2;
        $valor  = 1500;
        $date = '2019-12-23';
        $valor_parcela = $valor / $parcelas;
        $boletos = [];

        for (
            $i = 1;
            $i <= $parcelas;
            $i++
        ) {
            $date_sum_month = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+{$i} month", strtotime($date)));
            $boletos += ["numero" => $i, "date" => $date_sum_month, "valor" => $valor_parcela];
        }


        return json_encode($boletos);
    }
```

RETORNO

```
{
  "numero": 1,
  "date": "23/01/2020",
  "valor": 750
}
```

RETORNO DESEJÁVEL

```
{
  "numero": 1,
  "date": "23/01/2020",
  "valor": 750
}

{
  "numero": 2,
  "date": "23/02/2020",
  "valor": 750
}
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se é um array não deve concatenar outras coisas no array, precisa usar um posicional ou fazer push de um novo item, assim por exemplo:

```
array_push($boletos, ["numero" => $i, "date" => $date_sum_month, "valor" => $valor_parcela]);
```

Referência: [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)